# How to fix an error after changing token to new one in mapbox link

Tags: token, mapbox

I had to change a mabox token in this code to new one

```js
L.tileLayer(
        "https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=REPLACED THIS PART WITH A NEWLY GENERATED TOKEN",
        {
          zoom: 16,

          id: "mapbox.streets",
        }
      ).addTo(map);
```

and it doesn't work any more. It gives just a grey background. How to fix it?

Comment: Can you check the error message that is thrown into the console of your browser?

Comment: Hi Moritz. The error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 410 (Gone).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you are not seeing your map is most probably that you are using a deprecated classic style.

There are 2 ways to confirm that you are using this deprecated service.

I assume that `L` in your code stands for Leaflet so better go for option 2...

1. If you are using the APIs directly. The API is returning 410: gone error on a single raster tile or image request in the browser or using curl for requests. For example, for this request:

- https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.light/14/8185/5448@2x.png?access_token=Your_token_here,

you will see this response:
[image]

2. If you are using an application such as Leaflet or Mapbox.js. You would be able to confirm this once you retrieve a single tile or image request via your browser developer tool. Please take the following steps:

a. On your the web page that contains your map element, open the browser's developer tools.
b. Click the Network tab, and refresh your page. Here you see a new request to Mapbox API.
c. Double click or copy and paste a request that possibly looks like a number.png to a web browser and you will see the response similar to what you saw in step 1.

If you see the 410:gone error, please use these guidelines to migrate to modern styles:

- [Migrating to modern Static Image API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/migrate-legacy-static-images-api/#custom-classic-styles)
- [Migrating to modern Static Tiles API](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/migrate-legacy-static-tiles-api/#how-can-i-tell-if-my-style-is-a-classic-style-or-a-modern-mapbox-style)

If something else is unclear about migrating your classic styles please also check out the [classic styles FAQ](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/troubleshooting/migrate-legacy-static-tiles-api/#faqs) section of the troubleshooting guide.